# Pickling Django request objects

Tags: python, django, pickle

I'm trying to pickle a request object so that I can run my view code in a debugger with valid input. However, I'm getting

```
Can't pickle 'lock' object: <thread.lock object at 0x93ad240>
```

I looked through the request object, but couldn't find a thread.lock object anywhere in it. Does anyone know where it is? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: why can't you run your code directly into a debugger instead of trying to copy all state?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to debug the view code that gets run when a web request comes in. I guess I was thinking that it would be cleaner/simpler to just debug the views file and pass in a canned request rather than run all of django under the debugger and making an actual connection.

Comment: Additionally, I'm just curious what's going on here.

Comment: By "without making connection", do you mean that you don't want to connect your view to the urlsconf ?

Comment: This isn't urgent anymore - quite a while ago I went ahead and ran the main Django process under the debugger and it's working fine. However, it still seems like it would be nice to be able to do what I was trying. I would like to run just my views.py file under the debugger, decoupled entirely from the rest of Django. To do this, I wanted to pickle a valid HttpRequest and then unpickle it and call the view method in question on it.

Comment: why not to use tests framework? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#making-requests

Comment: Put a breakpoint just in front of the place in the pickle code that raises the error, and inspect the stack, locals, etc...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you cannot pickle HTTP requests objects for any web server. Pickling process does not pickle on the object itself, but all its references.

The usual web server design pattern is to have each HTTP request running its own thread. There must be a connection between the thread and HTTP request. Thus, the HTTP object is tied to the life cycle of web server and cannot be taken out of the web server context.

What you probably want to do is to pickle the contents of HTTP request object and re-create requests using this content as a payload.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to the original poster. Do you know how to " pickle the contents of HTTP request object and re-create requests using this content as a payload."? I can't find any documentation on how to do this on the net.

Comment: You can't find documentation because you cannot expect someone has already solved all problems for you :)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/

Just pick request.POST or request.GET payload or whatever contains everything coming from the user.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, for those who are interested, I have managed to pickle `HttpRequest` and `WSGIRequest` objects.
First, you will need to monkey-patch at least one class, `WSGIRequest` (and probably `HttpRequest`), so that it exposes a `__reduce__(self)` method. You would something like:

```
WSGIRequest.__reduce__= __reduce__
```

The `reduce` method may look like this:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    meta = dict([(k,self.META[k]) for k in METACOPY if k in self.META and isinstance(self.META[k], str)])
    return (HttpRequest, (), {'META':meta, 'POST':self.POST, 'GET':self.GET, 'user':self.user, 'path':self.path})
```

where `METACOPY` is a list of keys you want to keep, eg. ['REMOTE_ADDR']

I find it handier and more transparent than the payload method (which I used with celery before).

Comment: this gets to the meat of the problem - some unpicklable objects from `wsgi` are stored in the META dict

Comment: And if I remember correctly, there also was an unpickable thread lock object in the request's attributes.

Comment: Here, `session` is not pickable too. Some lambda is attached