# Django-celery : Passing request Object to worker

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

How can i pass django request object to celery worker. When try to pass the request object it throws a Error

```
Can't Pickle Input Objects
```

It seems that celery serialize any arguments passed to worker.
I tried using other serialization methods like JSON.

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "JSON"
```

But it is not working.

Is it possible to configure celery so that it won't serialize data. Or can i convert request object to a string before passing to worker and then convert again back to object in worker.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Converting to string and converting back to object is called serialization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't pickle Django's request objects (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103638/pickling-django-request-objects) for more details). Instead you should pass the relevant information from the request object that you need to the Celery tasks.

You should have no problem passing other information to a Celery task as most objects can be pickled without a problem.