# How can I store a Django request so that it can be repeated/rerun for debugging?

Tags: python, django, debugging, httprequest

Chrome has nifty feature whereby in the network requests inspector...:

[image]

...you can copy the whole request as a cURL command:

[image]

This means you can re-run the **exact** request again and again to facilitate debugging.

I have a situation where I have a small set of Beta testers using a Django site that is accessed from various native mobile apps, as well as desktop and mobile browsers.

When a very niche bug arises they send me a report, and of course the first thing I want to do is repeat the bug. To enable this I would like to be able to store the Django `request` object in my database and then later pull it out and re-run it at will, with the same headers, payloads, user-agent and everything - so the Django application thinks the request is simply being received identically again.

I already have a middleware to catch the `request` object for every request and save the `request.META` info to the DB.

Is there a way to go beyond this so that the entire request can be stored and re-run at will?

Comment: so it's a serialization problem - can you pickle the request object?

Comment: Apparently [you can - with some caveats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103638/pickling-django-request-objects). But it's not so much that I want the Python request object - I simply want the ability to re-send, identically, the same request as a user has previously sent.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reconstruct the request capabilities by extracting the header information from your logs. So first step would be to make sure you have all the requests logged (standard logging will do) and that you extract from the request all the information you deem necessary.

If you want to see what happens in the context of a user for that request then you need to be able to construct a valid user session first (for that specific user). You can solve this with a simple middleware solution but there are also libraries that provide you with those capabilities.